# $40 of peercoin mined per day: possible?

Tags: mining-profitability, peercoin

I have a friend who tells me she mines $40 worth of PPC per day per machine.  She has around 5  Cointerra ASIC servers working all day long.  One server is part of a pool.

I don't know enough about the rates.  But to me, it sounds very unlikely.

Is this, in fact, possible?

Comment: Are the servers using CPUs, GPUs, ASICs, ..? It would take some serious firepower to make $40/day, but connecting it to 5 servers is not unreasonable (I'd guess). 5 servers worth of CPUs? No way.

Comment: They're Cointerra ASICs.

Answer (score 2):

It would take [around 1.6 TH/s](http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/) to mine that as BTC and then exchange it, or 2 TH/s to mine [that much PPC](http://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/peercoin-mining-calculator/?h=2000&p=500.00&pc=0.10&pf=0.00&d=172827508.00576200&r=87.20740256&er=0.00470000&btcer=448.57000000&hc=0.00) (not counting minting the PPC that you're mining, which is supposed to work out to 1% per year).

Cointerra sells a [1.6 TH/s miner](https://cointerra.com/product/terraminer-iv-1-6-ths-bitcoin-miner/) for $3,500. With this $17,500 investment (plus any computers, electricity, maintenance, time, etc. associated with that), yes, she is mining $200/day on average currently (but ever-decreasing as the difficulty goes up), subject to market volatility. If only one is part of a pool and the rest are solo mining, that means she's taking the chance that she might never get anything of value from those 4 servers. That is a pretty high stakes [gamble](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/25244/12034), if you ask me.