# I'm running an antminer solo on my local bitcoind 'pool' will i get paid?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability, solo-mining, antminer

I'm running an antminer 'a' solo on my local bitcoind 'pool' plus an S5. Both are hashing away lovely, but only the S5 goes through bfgminer, 'a' is connected to my bitcoind 'pool' directly . My question is - what wallet will it use if any i.e. my bitcoin core wallet or can i add my own wallet to bitcoin.conf or some other way as bfgminer does not recognize 'a' or am i missing something here ?

Comment: solo mining? I believe the network hashrate is around 45 Exa hash/sec, you probably have 8 or 9 Tera hash/sec. Your chance of winning a block is something like 1 in 10 million so you probably want to use an actual pool.

Comment: AAH you said the word 'CHANCE' (It's true i have a chance) I'm trying solo to see how it goes, I'm also pool mining with my S9's

Comment: lol "so you're telling me there's a chance!"

Comment: Well, i may be wrong, but i'm definitely going to find out one way or the other (maybe never, maybe tomorrow) , Optimism is not a dirty word it's a state of mind which allows new or unlikely things to happen. I wont be disappointed if i don't find a block, or if i do :)

Comment: I'm not a big gambler, but if that's your thing, best of luck to you @Mike!

Comment: Thanks JBaczuk, i'll post here WHEN i find the first block.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/16687/5406, http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/14346/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/24185/5406

Comment: not a duplicate because the question is about the destination wallet address of an antminer thats not recognized by bfgminer

Comment: Does BFGMiner support Antminer S9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chances of *any* return whatsoever with a pool that's just you are essentially non-existent.

Pool mining works since pools can accumulate a large amount of hashpower from thousands of users. The pool's chance of finding a block is then fairly high, which then allows them to use the block reward to pay proportional amounts to all their users.

As JBackzuk's comment says, solo mining is essentially probabilistically impossible. You either find the entire block, or nothing - no partial shares.

Comment: I understand (and use) pools and i understand (and use) the lottery, i think why not mix it up a bit so not convinced, thats quite pessimistic (you may say 'realistic') but every solo miner has a chance, no matter how slight. But more to the point what will happen if i find a block on the V9, which wallet , if any, will it attempt to pay to ?

Comment: If you're using Bitcoin Core to get the blocktemplate, the coinbase transaction should be paying out to an address in your bitcoind wallet

Comment: Thankyou, i was veering that way but would have liked to use my other wallet if it was possible, but any wallet thats mine will do :)

Comment: also a wallet is not the same as an address. wallet is the software

Comment: Yes, i was meaning the addresses for different wallets, thanks