# mine the transactions on solo

Tags: transaction-fees, solo-mining

Will i receive the transactions fee even if i don't find a block?

If i create a personal pool and start mining in it is there a chance to find block?

Even if i don't find a block and for e.g mine 30 transaction will i earn the fees from those transactions?

And can i config my pool in a way to mine some specific transactions?

I think this is the first time this question is asked.

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't really any such thing as "mining transactions".  Mining is the process of finding blocks whose hash gives an appropriate proof of work.  Those blocks in turn contain transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product of mining is a block. You cannot "mine transactions" without finding a block, nor is there any reward except when you find a block.

When you mine, you do get to pick the transactions you want to confirm. For a more comprehensive description see: [What exactly is Mining?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/148/5406)

The profitability of solo mining has been covered here: [What are the odds of discovering a block as a solo miner?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/14346/5406), [Solo mining just for luck, realistic?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/16687/5406). In short, it's not profitable unless you have humongous mining power.

Comment: So if i connect to a bitcoincore that is sending the transactions and mine there i will confirm the transactions on that client first?

Comment: Your Bitcoin Core will verify the validity of the transaction, but it will be confirmed, when someone finds a block that includes the transaction. Verification only checks if the transaction adheres to the rules of the protocol, while confirmation actually writes the transaction to he blockchain, i.e. commits the network to consider it done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mining in a pool, you're no longer "Solo Mining" - and unless you have an Application-specific integrated circuit (ASIC), a machine made for SHA-256 cryptography, you can rest assured your chances of receiving any kind of reward for work by mining is next to nil.

The reward only goes to those that successfully mines the block and confirms the transactions - so the first person to do it gets all of the fees. When you mine in a pool, you come together as a community and agree on a set of rules for distributing the reward.

I'm afraid as to your last inquiry fringes on my lack of knowledge on this subject - but I suppose if the different nodes you are connected to have differing transactions, then yes - you would be able to choose which ones of those you'd like to confirm (Probably the ones with higher transaction fees) - but I could be wrong.

If you plan on going into mining I feel this link has invaluable information:
http://bitcoinminer.net/

If you are actually interested in the clever proof of work scheme you may find this link particularly interesting:
http://alexgorale.com/how-proof-of-work-works

If you do decide to take up mining, unless you want to spend ludicrous amounts of money to compete with the mining pools already established, I'd suggest you join a mining pool.

Hope I answered your questions and cleared some things up. :)